# Python sys.path appends wrong directories

Tags: python, directory

I'm trying to add directories to sys.path so Python looks there for modules. When I add a directory using append or insert command and then print out directories in sys.path, the directory I've just added is wrong. For example if I add "C:\Users\user\test", in sys.path it's "C:\Users\user   est"

It's not just the problem with the name displayed incorrectly, because modules don't load, so the right directory must have not been added.

I've tried commands: sys.path.append("xxx") and sys.path.insert(0, "xxx"). I've tried single and double quotation marks, and forward and backward slashes.

I'm using Anaconda Prompt (Anaconda 2) and Windows 10.

Comment: Have you tried  'C:"\\"Users"\\"user"\\"test' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're not properly escaping backslashes. Without seeing your code, it's hard to diagnose it more accurately, but try creating the directory with the string `user\\test` instead. Otherwise, python might interpret `\t` as an escape sequence, and replace it with a tab.

Comment: Glad to help. Please remember to accept the answer if it addresses your question. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1):

I think the right command should be

```
sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\user\\test')
```